# Can't get google map to appear in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I'm attempting to display a google map in an Ionic app. I can create the map object, but I cant seem to make it display in the application page. The result is the  in map.html with no visible google map in it. The $scope.centerOnMe() function also seems be working, but with no map to display, its useless.

I used the ionic sidemenu as a base for my project, and used code based on this repository (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-maps) to create a google map in one of the pages.

Here is my code:
**index.html**

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>


    <!-- compiled css output -->
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/itemCard.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>-->


    <!-- GOOGLE MAPS -->
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[myKey]0Q&sensor=true"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

**js/directives.js**

```
angular.module('starter.directives', [])

.directive('map', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      onCreate: '&'
    },
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493, -89.381388),
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map($element[0], mapOptions);

        $scope.onCreate({map: map});

        // Stop the side bar from dragging when mousedown/tapdown on the map
        google.maps.event.addDomListener($element[0], 'mousedown', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
        });
      }

      if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        initialize();
      } else {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

and **controllers.js**

```
    .controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile, StoreService) {

  $scope.mapCreated = function(map) {
    console.log("Creating");
    $scope.map = map;
    console.log($scope.map);
  };

  $scope.centerOnMe = function () {
    console.log("Centering");
    if (!$scope.map) {

      return;
    }

    $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
      content: 'Getting current location...',
      showBackdrop: false
    });

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
      console.log('Got pos', pos);
      $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
      $scope.loading.hide();
    }, function (error) {
      alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
    });
  };

})
```

**map.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Map">

  <ion-content>
    <!--<div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true">Map</div>-->
    <map on-create="mapCreated(map)"></map>
    <div>
      <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="alert()">X</button>
      <a ng-click="centerOnMe()" class="button button-icon icon ion-navigate">Find Me</a>
    </div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and finally **style.css**

```
#map {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 100px;
```

}

What should be noted here is that in controller.js, the $scope.mapcreated(map) function logs the map object. (You don't need to see the whole object, but it shows that the object has been created, and can be added to the page) Here is the result:

```
__e3_

    Object { resize={...},  zoom_changed={...},  streetview_changed={...},  more...}
__gm

    Oi { ca=map,  Sf=tg,  S=rg,  more...}
center

    rf { A=43.07493,  F=-89.38138800000002,  toString=function(),  more...}
controls

    [undefined, rg { j=[0],  gm_accessors_={...},  length=0,  more...}, rg { j=[0],  gm_accessors_={...},  length=0,  more...}, 11 more...]
data

    ei { gm_accessors_={...},  map=Sk,  gm_bindings_={...},  more...}
features

    T { gm_accessors_={...},  gm_bindings_={...},  get=function(),  more...}
gm_accessors_

    Object { bounds={...},  projection={...},  svClient={...},  more...}
gm_bindings_

    Object { reportErrorControl={...},  center={...},  zoom={...},  more...}
mapTypeId

    "roadmap"
mapTypes

    jh { gm_accessors_={...},  roadmap=GE,  gm_bindings_={...},  more...}
mapUrl

    "https://maps.google.com/...S&gl=US&mapclient=apiv3"
overlayMapTypes

    rg { j=[0],  gm_accessors_={...},  length=0,  more...}
streetView

    Mi { __gm=T,  controls=[14],  A=false,  more...}
tilt

    0
tosUrl

    "https://www.google.com/i...US/help/terms_maps.html"
zoom

    16
constructor

    Sk(a, b)
addListener

    function(a, b)
bindTo

    function(a, b, c, d)
changed

    function()
fitBounds

    function(a)
get

    function(a)
getBounds

    function()
getCenter

    function()
getDiv

    function()
getHeading

    function()
getMapTypeId

    function()
getProjection

    function()
getStreetView

    function()
getTilt

    function()
getZoom

    function()
notify

    function(a)
panBy

    function(a, b)
panTo

    function(a)
panToBounds

    function(a)
set

    function(a, b)
setCenter

    function(c)
setHeading

    function(c)
setMapTypeId

    function(c)
setOptions

    function(a)
setStreetView

    function(c)
setTilt

    function(c)
setValues

    function(a)
setZoom

    function(c)
streetView_changed

    function()
unbind

    function(a)
unbindAll

    function()
__proto__

    Sk { constructor=Sk(),  streetView_changed=function(),  getDiv=function(),  more...}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having similar issues just using the nightly build.  The width and height are set, I have my API key in the URL, but no map loads in the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Are there errors or something wrong in your console ?

Try adding [lodash.js](https://lodash.com/) before your Google Map API JavaScript.
It could help. :)

```
<script src="lib/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[myKey]0Q&sensor=true"></script>
```

Comment: I added lodash and there seems to be no visible effect. The console doesn't throw any errors during application loading. However, on centerOnMe(), the console throws the error: $ionicLoading instance.hide() has been deprecated. Use $ionicLoading.hide(). Which I'm ignoring until I can get the map to appear at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to style this
`<map on-create="mapCreated(map)"></map>`

with this

```
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 100px;
}
```

I'm willing to bet money there is no element with id #map.

Try this style instead:

```
map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 100px;
}
```

It might seem small, but unless you have a style that sets height, the element will default to zero height.

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed PART of the problem, also I wasn't actually loading style.css. I've fixed that, so the <map> element is actually there. Sadly, it still contains no google map.

Comment: I'm trying to find differences between your app and mine but there aren't many. Our map-directives are identical for example. But if you try to init a map with invalid coordinates, it won't load, so here are mine just in case: `var mapOptions = {center : new google.maps.LatLng(28.2, 129.381388), zoom : 10, mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};` .  I use `<ion-content scroll="false">` for some issue I cant remember. I also have view-cache turned off.  `$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);` in app.config. And  `<map on-create="mapCreated(map)" data-tap-disabled="true"></map>`.

Comment: I used the `ionic start myapp maps` template by the way. Does that work for you? It should run the map out of the box.

Comment: And are you sure you have activated the google maps api (the javascript v3 one) in the google api console?

Comment: I used have an in progress side-menu app that I'm trying to build with the map integrated in one of the pages. I used [$ionic start myapp maps] and used my api key on it and it works just fine. But when I move the code into the side-menu app, and start it up with $ionic serve, the map page seems to load a TINY <div> which looks like it has a map inside, but it disappears a split second later. Very odd...